# How can I modify Windows right-click menu to search for selected text?

Tags: windows-10

So at my company we have an internal portal where you can search a fellow employees login to see basic information about them like location, job role, years at the company etc. I do this like x10 a day and I would appreciate a quicker way to do this.

At the moment I copy the login and go to a URL like: https://contacts.wallmart.com (not the actual URL, just made an analogous example). Then on this site you can enter the login which will redirect you to the specified user. For example, if I wanted to know more about Cameron Smith who has the login CamSmith then I'd search this and the returned page would be:

https://contacts.wallmart.com/users/CamSmith

Similarly, Adam Gibbs whose login is AdaGibbs would have a contact page like:

https://contacts.wallmart.com/users/AdaGibbs

So the format is always: https://contacts.wallmart.com/users/LOGIN

where LOGIN is the relevant login of the employee you are querying. I want a way to add an option to the right click menu on Windows so that when I select a login e.g. CamSmith I can right-click and then click an option such as "Search in Wallmart Contacts" such that I am redirect to https://contacts.wallmart.com/users/CamSmith. So basically the option in the right click menu redirects me to URL https://contacts.wallmart.com/users/LOGIN but replaces LOGIN with the text I have selected.

I am a novice but this can't be too hard to do?

Comment: If you can edit the registry on the PC and install third-party software, [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com) might offer a potential solution. That said, if you have an IT department, you may want to confirm with them that these options are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the portal, and if it is web-based, then the easiest thing to do would be to modify the portal so that you have a link to the contact page for each user.  You can also with JavaScript handle a right-click action on the portal in order to get to the information you want.  Both of those options require some light knowledge of web application programming.

Alternatively, many mouse drivers will allow you to customize the right-click action, but this isn't usually context-sensitive... meaning that the customization you do will probably happen everywhere, not just in your portal.

The hardest thing would be to actually modify the Windows context/right-click menu.  It would require a lot of specialized knowledge.